# Reprojecting coordinates using gdalwarp and OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, gdalwarp

I have an interpolated raster image with EPSG:27700 (British National Grid), after I warp it using gdalwarp into EPSG:3857 (WGS84 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere)):

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:27700 -t_srs EPSG:3857 input.tif output.tif
```

which works fine (GDAL 1.10.1), (including a little bit of twisting (black cells) in the output one which is understandable as I guess there must be a little bit of distortion).

Then, if I create a Web Map Service (wms) in Geoserver using the output file as datastore, when I display the wms in a web page, by using OpenLayers and Google Maps as background, the image is not perfectly located, as it is misplaced about 90-100 meters LEFT where it should be in the British National Grid projection.

My question is whether gdalwarp does not the right transformation and/or OpenLayers does its best and does not adjust it, or it is definitely impossible to transform 27700 into 3857 accurately.

Comment: Which GDAL version? Do you use some open data image from Ordnance Survey so others can make a try with the same image? Do you know that using gdalwarp is not necessary because GeoServer can reproject on-the-fly from EPSG:27700? That is actually a good test. Make another WMS layer from the original image and see if original and reprojected versions are placed into same place in your OpenLayers application.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/raster-incorrectly-reprojected-to-osgb27700. Older versions of GDAL may contain an outdated datum shift parameterset.

Comment: GDAL 1.10.1. I have tried not to use gdalwarp and use the geoserver reprojection on-the-fly from epsg:27700 and the result is the same as before, which makes me happy partially as now I know that gdalwarp and geoserver reproject in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did work but using EPSG:102113 instead, not EPSG:3857.

This post helped me a lot:

[Reprojecting WGS 1984 Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) in Python with GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/reprojecting-wgs-1984-web-mercator-epsg3857-in-python-with-gdal)